# C++ Borland address of the variable

Tags: c++, variables, c++builder

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int *pInt;
        int iParam = 423425;
        pInt = &iParam;
        std::cout<<&pInt<<std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Why am i getting address like 1250008 and not like 0x00000 ?

Comment: What do you mean by " not like 0x00000"? Why it's not hex, or why it's not 0?

Comment: Then the asnwer is pretty easy - because an address is just a number and by default, c++ prints the numbers in decimal. So, you need yo use i/o manipulator, as @Als points in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns you the addresss where `pInt` is located in virtual memory.
It can be any address. The compiler is free to place an pointer at any address in the address space allocated to an process.

If you mean to get the address in `hex` and not decimal, you need to do use **[I/O Manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/hex/)** like this:

```
std::cout << hex << &pInt << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the statement printf("%x", iParam), The value stored in iParam is converted into hex and printed but it will not be started with 0X. The same scenario is also in case of printing address. It does not starts with 0X.